# updating/changing values in a nested array in Javascript ES9

Tags: javascript

The array

```
let data = [{
      "Name": "bob",
      "_assets": [{
          "income": "100,000",
          "Car": {
            "Name": "Honda",
            "Color": "White"
            },
            "Boat": {
              "Name": "Bertram ",
              "Color": "White"
            }
          }]
      }];
```

The output i'm trying to get is this

```
[{
  " Name": "bob",
  "_assets": [{
    "income": "100,000",
    "Car": "Honda",
    "Boat": "Bertram"
  }]
}];
```

Now I've been able to change the nested data, but in the process I lose the outer array. I've done plenty of googling, played around with different answers. Now I'm just burnt on something that seems so easy, but for some reason I'm just completely missing it.

Edit what I'm currently getting

```
[{
    "income": "100,000",
    "Car": "Honda",
    "Boat": "Bertram"
  }]
```

Comment: All you need is `.map()`.

Comment: What do you mean by _"lose the outer array"_? What code are you using and what result are you getting?

Comment: You are missing one `"` in the code (after `"Color": "White`). Not sure if it is part of your real code error or just typo on stackoverflow. Pointing out just in case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use nested `map`:

```js
let data = [{
      "Name": "bob",
      "_assets": [{
          "income": "100,000",
          "Car": {
            "Name": "Honda",
            "Color": "White"
            },
            "Boat": {
              "Name": "Bertram ",
              "Color": "White"
            }
          }]
      }];
      
      
        data = data.map(t => {
            return {
                "Name": t.Name, "_assets": t._assets.map(x => {
                    return {
                        "income": x.income, "Car": x.Car.Name, "Boat": x.Boat.Name
                    }

                })
            }
        })

        console.log(data);
```